# Create and populate custom object in Salesforce

Tags: api, rest, custom, object

I have built a custom survey system, and I would like to see the option on saving the results in Salesforce, on a custom object. In general, the object will have the following fields:

- Start date (datetime field)
- End date (datetime field)
- Question type (text)
- Question (text)
- Response (text)
- Contact_id (for logged in users, to be able to connect with an existing contact)

I am not interested on treating the above as attributes but as a custom standalone object, since the user might run multiple surveys, which means that we need to keep all of them (and through the Contact_id field it will make the connection to the contacts).

I am interested, the whole communication to take place through REST API calls (PHP/curl specifically) for creating the survey records in Salesforce.

Is there any clear example with guidelines on how to do this?

Comment: A better design would be to separate the survey and the questions into separate objects. At any rate, the documentation for the REST API (specifically for [creating a record](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm)) is going to be helpful here. The only thing that documentation doesn't really explain is that custom objects and custom fields need `__c` at the end.

Comment: I.e. you would be sending a request to the `https://MyDomainName.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v59.0/sobjects/My_Survey__c/` endpoint, and the JSON body would include things like `"start_date__c": "2023-11-25T15:25:30Z"` and `"Response__c":"fish taco"`

Comment: Be sure to start with Salesforce Trailhead for tutorials, and also check on Youtube channels from Salesforce and others like Salesforce Apex Hours for detailed examples.

Comment: Thank you guys! I'll take a look into the documentation!